# How to set enum in datatable ColumnProperty of nopcommerce 4.4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, view, enums, nopcommerce

I want to set enum in datatable ColumnProperty of nopcommerce 4.4.

I tried things like

```
new ColumnProperty(nameof(await(((TransmitEnumStatus)Model.StatusId).ToSelectListAsync())))
    {
    Title = T("Admin.Catalog.TransmitProduct.Fields.DriverNo").Text
    },
```

but didnt work it.

Is enum has applied in nopcommerce datatable column property? if yes then in which form?

Or else how can I implement enum in datatable column property.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Areas/Admin/Views/Log/List.cshtml` file for an example usage of an Enum column:

```cs
    new ColumnProperty(nameof(LogModel.LogLevel))
    {
        Title = T("Admin.System.Log.Fields.LogLevel").Text,
        Width = "100"
    },
```

Also, the `src/Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Models/DataTables/ColumnProperty.cs` file has a [reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data):

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Set the data source for the column from the rows data object / array.
        /// See also "https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data"
        /// </summary>
        public string Data { get; set; }
```

According to your needs, you might also use the `Render` property in the .cshtml file and set it to a javascript function to render your desired html to the user: *(there are different examples present if you search for `Render` in cshtml files)*

```cs
Render = new RenderCustom("render_function_name")
// render_function_name should be a javascript function present in the same cshtml file
```